# SQL Server Service Broker Performance Metrics

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker, dmv

Im looking at `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` table for performance metrics of Service broker. Below is the query:

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters  
         where object_name = 'SQLServer:Broker Statistics'
```

The confusion is, Im getting same values for
**SQL SENDs/sec** & **SQL SEND Total**

and also same values for **SQL RECEIVEs/sec** & **SQL RECEIVE Total**

Please explain why these values are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view exposes the raw values. You need to adjust according to the [counter type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394569.aspx). See [Interpreting the counter values from `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/09/23/interpreting-the-counter-values-from-sys-dm-os-performance-counters.aspx):

> For per-second counters, this value is cumulative. The rate value must be calculated by sampling the value at discrete time intervals. The difference between any two successive sample values is equal to the rate for the time interval used.